# Why are there parenthesis after the value of this variable in Swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Why are there parenthesis after the value of the entries variable in Swiftui?  What does this mean?

```
func barChartItems() -> [ChartDataEntry] {
    var entries = [ChartDataEntry]()
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is the empty init() required by `RangeReplaceableCollection` protocol which Array structure conforms to.

Comment: That’s the same as `var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = []` which I prefer.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a syntax to create an object of an empty typed array of `ChartDataEntry` type.

[Creating an Empty Array](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html)

```
var someInts = [Int]() // an empty array of Int
```

Answer (score -1):

Specifically the parenthesis following the declaration is the init() method call for the class or type. Because an Array type can be created without any init variables they are not needed to initialize the Array type, in-fact Swift best practice is not to add them if you aren't passing anything:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

In the case of a class, you always need the parenthesis to create an object instance from the class.

I built a small SwiftUI example with an @Observable class that has an multiple init() options. You can see how the init() parameters can change the properties of the object by calling the different initializers:

```
class MultipleInitOptions:ObservableObject {
    @Published var name = "hard coded name"
    
    init(){} // has no parameters, just use empty parenthesis
    
    init(name:String) { // has parameters, pass in a name parameter inside parenthesis
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct TesterView: View {
    @StateObject var hardCoded = MultipleInitOptions()
    @StateObject var custom = MultipleInitOptions(name:"custom name")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(hardCoded.name)")
                .padding()
            Text("\(custom.name)")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```